# Need to delete a wordpress website from Cpanel

Tags: hosting

I am a Maker. I am new to wordpress.com. I have registered a domain like example.com with the help of bluehost. I have got access to cpanel. There I installed **wordpress** for **example.com/wp** instead of example.com. Now my webpage is displayed on net as **example.com/wp**.

I want to uninstall and re-install wordpress again for example.com/. I want all the old stuff/files to be purged (There is no data on the website as of now). Can anyone help me for this? I am really new to this. Please help me with step-by-step instructions for this.

Comment: You don't need to reinstall, you can just follow the directions for [Using a pre-existing subdirectory install](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install) to serve your site from the domain root.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of delete, you can move all files from `/wp` to `root` folder.

Then use this script to replace url from `example.com/wp` to `example.com` inside the database https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Follow these few steps.

1. Move all your website files to root from `/wp` folder.
2. Upload the script folder to your web root.
3. Browse to the script file URL in your web browser. eg. http://example.com/Search-Replace-DB/
4. Fill in the fields as needed.
5. Hit on run button

It will replace all your old string to your new string inside the database.

Comment: @markratledge older version(2.1.0)  of `search and replace` script is much easier to use, than the latest one.

Answer (score -1):

**Move Site  No need to Delete**

Step-1 : Login to Cpanel and move all folder to root folder (Normally public_html)

Step-2 : Now,Show hidden file and rename htaccess file.

Step-3 : Goto Database (i.e. phpmyadmin) and open wp_options table.Change site_url and home_url make it to (http://example.com)

Step-4 : Login to admin panle go to Settings and update paramlinks.

Step-5 :That's it.

**Some Issue while Move site**

1. Home Page not displayed : Go to appreance and active theme again.
2. Admin is not open or white screen:  Reupload all except wp-content folder
3. 404 Page Not Found : Remove htaccess and update paramlinks
4. Site navigate to old url : change home_url and site_url

Comment: Absolutely wrong answer.

Comment: why?? may i know??